# How do i cast a reference in my firebase database that could be of two different types

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to reference something in my database by the snapshot method(?).

Im creating a small pizza app

```swift
ref.child("Resturants").child("Da GiGi").child("pizzas").observeSingleEvent(of:.value, with: {(snapshot) in
    for granchild in (snapshot.children){
        let pizzaSnap = granchild as! DataSnapshot
        let dict = pizzaSnap.value as! [String: String??] // I get an error here: "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

        let nameUse = dict["name"] as? String
        let priceUse = dict["price"] as? String
        let toppingsUse = dict["toppings"] as? String

    }
}
```

In my firebase database i have "" around the name and the toppings, but not around my price, which means the price is not of type string. My code works if i change the type of the price to the string type.

I tried to eliminate `let dict`:

```swift
ref.child("Resturants").child("Da GiGi").child("pizzas").observeSingleEvent(of:.value, with: {(snapshot) in
    for granchild in (snapshot.children){
        let pizzaSnap = granchild as! DataSnapshot

        let nameUse = pizzaSnap.value["name"] as? String
        let priceUse = pizzaSnap.value["price"] as? String
        let toppingsUse = pizzaSnap.value["toppings"] as? String

    }
}
```

But now i obviously get some errors.

How do i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is have the dictionary of type `[String:Any]` instead of `[String:String]`:

```swift
ref.child("Resturants").child("Da GiGi").child("pizzas").observeSingleEvent(of:.value, with: {(snapshot) in
    for granchild in (snapshot.children){
        let pizzaSnap = granchild as! DataSnapshot
        let dict = pizzaSnap.value as! [String:Any] //Should no longer get an error

        let nameUse = dict["name"] as? String
        let priceUse = dict["price"] as? Float
        let toppingsUse = dict["toppings"] as? String


    }
}
```

If your price was, in fact, being stored as a `String`, like `"18.49"`, then you could cast the value as `[String:String]`. But anytime a dictionary has more than one value, you are going to want the dictionary's value type to be `Any`, like so: `[String:Any]`.

As you can see, we also are casting our price to a non-integer number instead of a `String`, in this case `Float`. If this casting fails, try casting the price as a `CGFloat` or `Double` instead.